# Change GeoServer's Home Directory with Jetty

Tags: geoserver, configuration, jetty

The title says it all. I would like to have GeoServer running on another path other than http://root_path:8080/geoserver/web.
I would like it to be http://root_path:8080/sub_path/geoserver/web.

The idea is having clustered GeoServers.

One running on

http://root_path:8080/sub_path1/geoserver/web

and another on

http://root_path:8080/sub_path2/geoserver/web

I am using the embed Jetty web server. 
If this is not possible with Jetty, is it possible with Tomcat?

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the `context-path` as [described here](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.3.x/configuring-contexts.html)